# British date format on Reporting server turns to US format on client side via MS SSRS

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I have problem retrieving correct date format on client side using MS [reporting service 2010](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/reportservice2010.reportingservice2010.aspx).

The British date format (18/05/2011) of date type is assigned to the default value of a parameter in a rdl file hosted on the reproting server. However, when the date value becomes US format (5/18/2011) via reporting service 2010.

```
 ReportingService2010 reportingService = new ReportingService2010();
 reportingService.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;

ItemParameter[] parameters = reportingService.GetItemParameters(reportUrl, historyId, forRendering, values, credentialses);

 foreach (var parameter in parameters)
                {

               //parameter.DefaultValues //date value changed from British value to US
                }
```

Any idea?

[Accessing the SOAP API](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms154052.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

I have to create a partial class alongside the generated ReportingService class and override the GetWebRequest method, then add an Accept-Language header to the Web request. Here is a sample class:

```
public partial class ReportingService

{

 protected override System.Net.WebRequest GetWebRequest(Uri uri)
    {
        WebRequest request = base.GetWebRequest(uri);

        request.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.AcceptLanguage, CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name);

        return request;
    }

}
```